# How to use sticky CSS to cover heading content on scroll?

Tags: css

I'm trying to do a simple version of [this](https://www.texasdemocrats.org/). *I don't mean all the additional features (exit/close button, donation buttons, two-column layout).* Just the part that allows the entire page to function as one main section, while the top header call to action / alert sticks to the top of the page and is covered by the rest of the page on scroll. It's not only the navbar that's covering the blue section, it's the entire page.

I've tried to use CSS `position: sticky;` but I get mixed results. A lot of documentation does exist on using sticky, but there's not much I've found on achieving a result like the one linked above.

[image]

**Edit:** Here is how my code looks using each of the suggested methods. The results are the same however I've tried, where the header text runs beneath the main content and appears again at the bottom of that palm tree visual, and all the content is static with respect to the CSS effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried -webkit-position:sticky?
Or -moz-position:sticky?

Answer (score 0):

If you know/can set a height for the sticky content, then you can use position absolute on the box.

sticky box:

```css
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: -1;
height: 5em;
```

content below:

```
margin-top: 5em;
```

I'm using 5em as an example height here, but the idea is to have your content leave enough space for the sticky content, hence the `margin-top: 5em`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavaScript`.
Check when the `navbar` is at the top of the page when scrolling, if `true` add the class `fixed-navbar`, which styles the `navbar { position: fixed;}`, if not, remove the class.

```js
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var navTop = navbar.offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function() {
  checkNavbarPosition()
};

function checkNavbarPosition() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= navTop) {
    navbar.classList.add("fixed-navbar")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("fixed-navbar");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}

header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.fixed-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed-navbar + .container {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
  </ul>
</header>

<main>
  <nav id="navbar">
  </nav>
  
  <div class="container">
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  </div>
</main>
```

**EDIT**

For the fixed `header`, edited:

HTML

```
<main>
 <nav></nav>
 <div class="container"></div>
</main>
```

CSS

```
header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* You may need to change the background color depends on your design, 
and delete height property if needed */
main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
}

/* padding top is added to the container 
to prevent the glitch when styling the navbar to be fixed (Read below) */
.fixed-navbar + .container {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

- The `Adjacent Sibling Selector (+)` is used to target the `.container` that is **next (sibling)** to the `nav` when `fixed-navbar` class is added... You may need more lines of `JS` in case the order of the elements changed.

Comment: This is pretty great. Sorry I didn't clarify (just edited) but what if the navbar isn't the intent of the "stick" but rather the entire page. Does that mean you'd just assign such an ID to a new container that wraps the remainder of the page?

Comment: Let me know if I understand it right: you want the `main content` of the page to be fixed?

Comment: Or both `navbar` and `main`?

Comment: Added a gif in the original question for clarification, hope that helps. I just meant that the blue section in the example is fixed behind the main content.

Comment: Edited, check it now please